# Magento 2 "add to cart" modal in category page (grid)

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, popup, magento2

On a basic Magento 2 CE, I want to add a modal in category (and also product view) page when click-ing Add to Cart button, to display a popup with Product Image, Product Name, Product Price, Continue and View cart (links).

I've tried this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207780/magento2-add-to-cart-modal ,
but `addtocart.phtml` is not used in category page and I don't want to load the content of modal for every single item in category view. And I don't know any other options.

Someone suggest that i could use knockoutjs. Any ideas?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this free extension: https://marketplace.magento.com/magekey-module-adc-popup.html .